# Android WindowManagerTypes.SystemOverlay clickable

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I have a float button on main screen like code below, but with WindowManagerTypes.SystemOverlay i can´t click in this button.
I need that button clickable and call my class.
Xamarin Android.
Please help me.

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    private static IWindowManager windowManager;
    private static ImageView imageView;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        if (Android.Provider.Settings.CanDrawOverlays(this))
        {
            ShowFloatView();
        }
        else
        {
            var intent = new Intent(Android.Provider.Settings.ActionManageOverlayPermission);
            StartActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, [GeneratedEnum] Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        ShowFloatView();
    }

    private void ShowFloatView()
    {
        windowManager = GetSystemService(WindowService).JavaCast<IWindowManager>();
        if (imageView != null)
        {
            windowManager.RemoveView(imageView);
        }
        imageView = new ImageView(Application.Context);
        imageView.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.iconeVermelho);
        WindowManagerLayoutParams paramsF = new WindowManagerLayoutParams(
            WindowManagerLayoutParams.WrapContent,
            WindowManagerLayoutParams.WrapContent,
            WindowManagerTypes.SystemOverlay,
            WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen,
            Format.Transparent);

        paramsF.Gravity = GravityFlags.Top | GravityFlags.Left;
        paramsF.X = 0;
        paramsF.Y = 100;
        windowManager.AddView(imageView, paramsF);
    }
```

==========================EDITED====================================

Look what i did. Work fine but on BotaoFlutuante_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e) the background color is chenged but not call my class and don´t show message. Can help me?

```
[Activity(Label = "SOSUber", MainLauncher = true)]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    private static IWindowManager windowManager;
    private static FloatingActionButton botaoFlutuante;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        if (Android.Provider.Settings.CanDrawOverlays(this))
        {
            ShowFloatView();
        }
        else
        {
            var intent = new Intent(Android.Provider.Settings.ActionManageOverlayPermission);
            StartActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }

        botaoFlutuante.Click += BotaoFlutuante_Click;

    }

    private void BotaoFlutuante_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        botaoFlutuante.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Green);
        EnviaSms enviarSms = new EnviaSms();
        enviarSms.EnviarSms();
        Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, "PAPAPAPAPA", ToastLength.Long);
    }

    protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, [GeneratedEnum] Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        ShowFloatView();
    }

    private void ShowFloatView()
    {
        windowManager = GetSystemService(WindowService).JavaCast<IWindowManager>();

        botaoFlutuante = new FloatingActionButton(this);
        botaoFlutuante.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Green);

        WindowManagerLayoutParams Params = new WindowManagerLayoutParams(WindowManagerLayoutParams.WrapContent,
                                                                         WindowManagerLayoutParams.WrapContent,
                                                                         WindowManagerTypes.SystemAlert,
                                                                         WindowManagerFlags.NotFocusable,
                                                                         Android.Graphics.Format.Translucent);

        Params.Gravity = GravityFlags.Center;
        windowManager.AddView(botaoFlutuante, Params);
    }
}
```

Comment: SystemOverlay can never be touchable or focusable.

Comment: Ok, i know. But how to do a clickable button that behave like a SystemOverlay? Because i need always on top and clickable. Thanks.

Comment: the closest you can get the the application overlay, which won't appear on the lockscreen.

Comment: I can't believe tha no have way to do a clickable button always on top of main screen.

Comment: It's for security. A touchable overlay on the lockscreen could track your password.

Comment: But its not on lockscreen. Its on the main screen, like facebook messenger chat button. Thanks

Comment: Then an application overlay will work fine. There's no reason to use the system overlay.

Comment: I don't find application overlay, only System. Based in my code, how i can implement? Thanks.

Comment: Use the Phone type then.

Comment: Can you help me? I'm beginner.